# Getting console errors in Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4.2

I'm getting lots of console errors after configure braintree in magento 2.4.2.

I'm attaching screenshot for same.

I added those in csp_whitelist.xml but no change into errors.
Does anyone know how to fix these errors ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in your module for example **app/code/Vendor/Module**

**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/csp_whitelist.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<csp_whitelist xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Csp:etc/csp_whitelist.xsd">
    <policies>
        <policy id="script-src">
            <values>
                <value id="newrelic_com" type="host">*.newrelic.com</value>
                <value id="nr_data_net" type="host">*.nr-data.net</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
        <policy id="connect-src">
            <values>
                <value id="nr_data_net" type="host">*.nr-data.net</value>
            </values>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</csp_whitelist>
```